# Changing YT video on jQuery timer expiration. How to change if page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, youtube-api

I'm trying to have a timer count down to a certain time. At that time I want the YouTube video to switch. This much I've gotten. The problem is when you refresh after the expiretime the page loads the original video instead of the new video.

My Current html looks like this
[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/1wpxaFgx)
This countsdown to +8 seconds and works fine. If I change that to a certain time it also works.. but then is when the refresh problem occurs.

> ```
> $(function () {
>         $('#switchtimer').countdown({
>                 alwaysExpire: true,         // run "change_video" if time has already expired when you load
>                 until: expire_date,             // timer counts down to expire_date
>                 onExpiry: change_video,         // when timer hits 0; run "change_video"
>                 });
> });
> ```

The issue seems to be with the **alwaysExpire: true,**
As per the documentation:

> On expiry a callback is made to allow you to action the countdown. You can force this event to fire even if the countdown starts after the target time by setting alwaysExpire to true.

and:

> **Name** - alwaysExpire
>   **Type** - boolean
>   **Default** - false
>   **Comment** - If true, the onExpiry event is triggered even when the counter starts after the target time. If false, the event only triggers if the counter actively times out.

I've tried rearranging the order it doesn't matter. I've tried true *and* false no luck. I've triple checked my spelling, I even tried replacing **alwaysExpire: true,** with **alwaysExpire = true** and still nothing. well actually that last one broke everything all together.

it also occurs to me to wonder if the problem might be my switching code but as I said that actually works.. as long as the page is actually loaded when the timer expires.

> ```
>       function change_video() {
>             ytid = next_vid
>             player.cueVideoById(ytid);
>         }
> ```

Ref: [Timer](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html) by Keith Wood

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at your HTML it is pretty normal that you having that issue since you are not giving it a way to remember what was the last video played. At load time the page always get initiated with this video:
var ytid = "CD2LRROpph0";
and you also have nextvid hardcoded. A way to approach this is to store the current video being played in a cookie, when page loads read from that cookie first the value of the video, if it is empty (the user has never been on this page) then feed it the default value. You could also store all your videos ids in an array for future scalability. 
Let me know if you need help with the actual cookie code, but this should get you going. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Cookies are a bit beyond my knowledge. Here's what I was thinking and you can tell me if my logic was wrong. I have series of videos A, B, C, D, E, etc. That I want to show starting Monday. I want my timer to countdown to 5pm and switch to the next video. My thoughts were if I set Today_video=A and Tomorrow_Video=B and then just have the timer arrange to display B anytime after 5. Then I can go in manually in the evening and cycle up Today_video=B Tomorrow_Video=C, and so forth. later on yeah i wanna use an array but shouldn't this work for now?

Comment: Assuming the user never gets to reload the page and uses it in a linear fashion that model you have will work, but you understand it's not solving your initial issue.

Comment: And actually looking closely at the countdown() method it seems like it is already taking care of setting up a cookie for you. Ok if time allows today I will run your code on my end and tell you with the best solution I can come up with. Cheers.

Comment: _Assuming the user never gets to reload the page and uses it in a linear fashion that model you have will work, but you understand it's not solving your initial issue._  -  I'm was thinking it shouldn't matter if they reload. If they reload and it's 7pm. The timer is over but `alwaysExpire:true` should ensure that it fires `change_video`. I'm just so close to getting this to work I'd rather not start over but if I have to, then so be it I guess.